# Object hierarchy is causing a memory leak in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Ive been able to distill a problem seen in an app I've written, and have reproduced it in a simple example.

Given these classes:

```
class Thing {
    var name:String = ""
    var price:Double = 0.0
    var changed:Double = 0.0
    var percentChanged:Double = 0.0
}

class TestUIViewController: UIViewController {

}

class ViewController: TestUIViewController {

    var thing:Thing?

    @IBAction func clicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.thing = Thing()
    }

}
```

I created a UIView with a button, that when pressed, a thing is instantiated. With the Instruments profiler up, I can see memory leaks occurring.

However, if the ViewController class extends from UIViewController, there are no issues.

This was all reproduced from a quick test app, so there are no other external forces at play here that i can think of.

Here is the example code - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ooqh77lhpzbvpv1/ArcTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: Try adding deinit methods with breakpoints in every class and let us know which of them are called and which are not after you ViewController instance is popped fron navigation stack (or dismissed modally). If all af them are called, you don't have a reason to worry and probably something is wrong with Profiler itself

Comment: Alex, the deinit is definitely being called. Before i noticed this in profiler, i saw the memory building up from within the Xcode debug session. If your feeling is that its a profiler issue, thats good enough for me. Im not recreating any views, or popping them off a stack.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is your use of Instruments? What does "I can see memory leaks occurring" actually mean? What, in fact, do you see? Did you use the Leaks instrument? Also, did you use the new Xcode 8 memory graphing feature?

Comment: Matt, here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing in Instruments https://www.dropbox.com/s/lc1lmksm8lmucw7/leaks.png?dl=0

Comment: Matt, the memory graph in Xcode is showing the leak as well.

Comment: @Brian I've tried to reproduce it but with no luck. Neither profiler nor xcode memory monitor show any issues. Can you please share your test project via dropbox, github or whatever?

Comment: Yes, Alex. Thank you so much. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ooqh77lhpzbvpv1/ArcTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: Merely saying my name (or Alex's) will not cause a message to be received. You must use at-sign and the person's username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have found a bug in the leak detector, and it could be quite an interesting bug, so you should report it to Apple. But there is in fact no leak. I downloaded and ran your project under Instruments and clicked the button 10 times. This is what I saw in Instruments allocations template:

[image]

That is the expected result. There are 9 transient Things, and only one persistent Thing — the one currently assigned to the property. A leak would be if there were more than one persistent Thing, and there isn't.

Also, this is what the memory gauge looks like in Xcode:

[image]

We get a little rise (a kind of "mesa") when I repeatedly tap the button, but then we settle back down to the base level again.