# Memory leaks Xcode 8 instrument

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks

I do nothing on my view controller and I see the graph that is changing while app is working.

Are this really leaks?

[image]

First time it show green check mark then it show 1 leak and then no new leaks.

So it means that there are no leaks or there are still 1 leak but not new ones?

I have actually app delegate which contains strong reference of manager.

```
class AppDelegate {

var applicationManager = ApplicationManager()

}
```

and I have few services in ApplicationManager

```
class ApplicationManager
{
  lazy var apiService: APIService = {

    let service = APIService()

    return service

  }()

  lazy var facebookService: FacebookService = {

    let service = FacebookService()

    return service

  }()
}
```

I have a function

```
func logInUser()
  {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
      fatalError()
    }

    let apiService = appDelegate.applicationManager.apiService

    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else {
      return
    }
    apiService.loginUserWith(email, password: password) {(result) in
}
```

could this code leads problems?

Using new tools I also see

that I have one leaked object (it's in another previous project) but with the same implementation of manager and services.

[image]

Comment: A leak is a leak; once an object has leaked, it has leaked forever. But it's just one object, once, so perhaps you don't really care. You can use Instruments to track down the memory management of the object in question, if you want to.

Comment: @matt, maybe smth wrong, yea I understood it) but strange that the service I only allocated cause a leaked, can I share sources?

Comment: There is a leak-reporting bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944703/object-hierarchy-is-causing-a-memory-leak-in-swift so perhaps your leak is not real.

Comment: @matt, yea possible, I also add project, so here are just 2 classed and few line of code which cause leaks)
thanks for help
https://github.com/matrosovDev/TestXcode8Leaks

Comment: I downloaded your project from github and ran it. I don't see any leaks, either in Instruments or in the Memory Graph in Xcode.

Comment: @matt thank you Matt, I appreciate it, hm strange I see leaks in Instrument and in Memory graph in Xcode 8.1 as I attached on screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that there is in fact no leak. The Xcode 8.2 release notes say:

> The Memory Debugger for macOS and the iOS Simulator fixes reporting of false memory leaks for Swift classes containing either fields of type enum, or classes that inherit from certain Objective-C framework classes. (27932061)

You are using Xcode 8.1, so we know that there is "reporting of false memory leaks for Swift classes" in this version (though under what precise circumstances, and whether the bug is completely fixed even in Xcode 8.2, remains unclear to me).

Moreover, I downloaded your github example project and ran it in Xcode 8.2.1 and saw no leak reported, neither in Instruments nor in the memory graph. Here's the Instruments output:

[image]

Comment: thank for help!) really appreciate it, as I supposed then all my apps were written with leaks, which is crazy) thank god and you